# Get ODataQueryOptions in HTTPPOST method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-grid, odata, odatacontroller

I am using HTTP POST for getting the data from the ODataController. But I m not able to query my service

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<MyDataObject> FetchCCMNewIssueLogViewGridData()
{
     var result = CCMModelDataContext.MyDataObject.AsQueryable();
     return result ;
}
```

How I can send request from the client side to accept as ODataQueryOptions object?

```
[HttpPost]        
public IQueryable<MyDataObject> FetchGridData(ODataQueryOptions<MyDataObject> options)
{
    var result = options.ApplyTo(CCMModelDataContext.MyDataObject.AsQueryable(), new ODataQuerySettings());
    return result as IQueryable<MyDataObject>;
}
```

But here in ODataQueryOptions object, I m getting 'Filter' and 'OrderBy' in the ODataQueryOptions  object as null.

Here is my kendo parameter map method for creating the request

```
parameterMap: function (data, type) {
    var newData = customFilterOptions.grdParameterMap(data, type);    
    return JSON.stringify(newData );
},
```

How I can achieve this?

No need to modify query options in the API Controller. 
In which format I can send data to API for accepting it as ODataQueryOPtions object.
As of now my 'Request payload' is

```
{$top: 20, $orderby: "field1 desc", $filter: "(field1 eq 2 and field2 eq 385)", $count: true, $skip : 20}
```

How I can do this? will this EnableQuery work with 'HTTP POST'?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I need to apply FilterQueryOption, OrderByQueryOption, TopQueryOption and SkipQueryOption separately to my IQueryable in my API?

Comment: What are you specifying in your request for the filter or order by?  Does your request look similar to http://localhost:12345/Endpoint?$filter=id+eq+100

Comment: Nop. I am sending an HTTP POST. The query string part is inside the body.

Comment: Oh, apparently I wasn't looking very closely. Have you seen this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168213/possible-to-post-odataqueryoptions-from-the-http-request-body

Comment: @mumfy : in that one, they are just passing the filter and using FilterQueryOption. I dont want to apply one by one. I m checking is there any do all the queries like filter , orderby, skip and  sort in one shot.

Comment: I m checking is there any way do all the queries like filter , orderby, skip and sort in one shot(using ODataQueryOptions).

Comment: @Ajay: did you solve this yet?